# How to highlight tags of a code block differently than its content?

Tags: vim, neovim

I have this code:

```
<start-1>
  some stuff here
  <start-2>
    some stuff here
  </start-2>
  <start-3>
    some stuff here
  </start-3>
  some stuff here
</start-1>
```

And I want to colorize as follows:

- Tags `<start-1>`, `</start-1>` to be in bold red.
- Content between `<start-1>` and `</start-1>` to be in italic red.
- Tags `<start-2>`, `</start-2>` to be in bold green.
- Content between `<start-2>` and `</start-2>` to be in italic green.
- Tags `<start-3>`, `</start-3>` to be in bold blue.
- Content between `<start-3>` and `</start-3>` to be in italic blue.

I tried:

```
syntax region start1 start=/<start-1>/ end=/<\/start-1>/ contains=t1,start2,start3
syntax region start2 start=/<start-2>/ end=/<\/start-2>/ contained contains=t2
syntax region start3 start=/<start-3>/ end=/<\/start-3>/ contained contains=t3

syntax match t1 /<\/\?start-1>/ contained
syntax match t2 /<\/\?start-2>/ contained
syntax match t3 /<\/\?start-3>/ contained

hi t1 ctermfg=red cterm=bold
hi t2 ctermfg=green cterm=bold
hi t3 ctermfg=blue cterm=bold

hi start1 ctermfg=red cterm=italic
hi start2 ctermfg=green cterm=italic
hi start3 ctermfg=blue cterm=italic
```

But fails as follows:

[image]

Not all of the content is colorized properly (i.e. green invaded all of blue's space, and the remaining bits of the red's space as well), and not all tags are in bold.

If I remove the tags `t1`, `t2`, and `t3`, I get this:

[image]

Which shows that all text colorization is done correctly.  I guess this means that, somehow, the tags matching is causing trouble to the `region`s knowing their boundaries.

**Questions:**

- What did I do wrong?
- What's the right way?

Comment: You should ask on [vi.se]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is only for reference.  The best answer is in the comments section by @nickspoon.

---

The solution was to add `keepend` as follows:

```
syntax region start1 start=/<start-1>/ end=/<\/start-1>/ keepend contains=t1,start2,start3
syntax region start2 start=/<start-2>/ end=/<\/start-2>/ keepend contained contains=t2
syntax region start3 start=/<start-3>/ end=/<\/start-3>/ keepend contained contains=t3

syntax match t1 /<\/\?start-1>/ contained
syntax match t2 /<\/\?start-2>/ contained
syntax match t3 /<\/\?start-3>/ contained

hi t1 ctermfg=red cterm=bold
hi t2 ctermfg=green cterm=bold
hi t3 ctermfg=blue cterm=bold

hi start1 ctermfg=red cterm=italic
hi start2 ctermfg=green cterm=italic
hi start3 ctermfg=blue cterm=italic
```

(sry didn't know https://vi.stackexchange.com/ exists -- moderators may feel free to relocate this, or delete it - i just posted the answer in case it helps).

Comment: No need to apologize! But we’d love to have you at [vi.se] 

Comment: You may also be interested in `matchgroup` - if you use this you don't need to define the matches t1,t2,t3 at all, you can totally remove lines 5,6,7 and instead define your regions like this: `syntax region start1 matchgroup=t1 start=/<start-1>/ end=/<\/start-1>/ keepend contains=start2,start3`

Comment: @nickspoon Thanks!  If you put it in an answer, I'll accept yours.  Meanwhile I put it in a note in my answers.

Comment: @caveman thanks, but I'll leave it as a comment - your answer of `keepend` is the correct answer, I just thought you might find `matchgroup` useful.